# XPages : Is there any way to force save NotesXspDocument?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'd like to force saving data of NotesXSPDocument to prevent creating conflict document in case users are opening the same document.
For NotesDocument, there is a option in NotesDocument.save method but not in NotesXSPDocument.save.

For instance, when clicking 'save' button, I think the next codes meets my requirement. However I have lots of custom control and fields, it is not a smart solution... Is there any other good solution?

```
    var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument();
    doc.replaceItemValue("Field1", data1);
    doc.replaceItemValue("Field2", data2);
    doc.replaceItemValue("Field3", data3);
    .....
    doc.save(true);
```

Comment: Does adding `concurrencyMode="force"`on the data source help?

Comment: Document locking?

Comment: Thanks. It looks like document locking has lots of points to consider. The concurrencyMode is a good option for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a datasource as described here: https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=save-datasource-fire-querysavepostsave-events

Comment: Thanks but ds.save( facesContext, true ); did not work. When opening the same document by two users, the user who opened the document later saves the document, and then the the user who opened the document firstly saves the document. The document are saved as a conflict document.

Comment: You have two choices: Build a locking mechanism for the document to prevent multiple users to work on the same document, or change the *concurrencyMode* property of the datasource: Then, the last one who saves the document wins, and all changes of other users will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like document locking has lots of points to consider. The concurrencyMode is a good option for me.